# Update Total Price Not Working with Input Buttons

Tags: javascript

So I made this simple checkbox and tip app.

Right now if I click a box it updates the price and the tip updates as well, however, it doesn't update the order total

Here is my code:

```js
function updatePrice() {
  //Adding Food
  let items = 0;

  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach((checkBox) => {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      items += +checkBox.value;
    }
  });

  //Adding Tip

  let tip = document.getElementById("tip");

  tip = 0;

  document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches("input[type=button]")) {
      tip = event.target.value;
      document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip: $${tip}`;
    }
  });

  //Calculating Totals

  let orderTotal = items + tip;

  document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(
    items / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;

  document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(
    orderTotal / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
    <h2>Order Details</h2>
        <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="1000" onClick="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item1">12 piece wings $10</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="700" onClick="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item2">6 piece wings $7</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="300" onClick="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item3">Large fries $3</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="payment">
    <h2>Payment Summary</h2>
    <p id="price">Food Total: $0.00</p>
    <p id="fee">Delivery Fee $0.00</p>
    <p id="tip">Tip: $0.00</p>
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="5">
    <input type="button" value="10">
    <p id="total">Your order total is: $0.00</p>
</div>
```

It looks like the tip isn't being moved past the function, so when I create the variable orderTotal, the tip value don't get added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it doesn't update the order total

Because there's no code to do that.  This is what the code does when you click a "tip" button:

```
tip = event.target.value;
document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip: $${tip}`;
```

As you can see, nothing in this operation affects the `orderTotal` or the display of that total.  You can update those as well by writing code to update them:

```
// update tip
tip = event.target.value;
document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip: $${tip}`;

// update total
// with calculations because your other values are multiplied by 100 for some reason
document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(
  (orderTotal + (tip * 100)) / 100
).toFixed(2)}`;
```

---

A few additional notes...

- Your `updateTotal` function is *re-binding* click handlers with `document.addEventListener` every time it executes.  This is probably not what you want and can lead to bugs.  Separate binding the event handlers from the logic executed by those handlers.
- The values being used are pretty much guaranteed to cause confusion at some point.  Pick a standard and stick with it.  Are values in "dollars" or in "cents"?  If you stick with one standard then you won't have to keep littering the code with `* 100` and `/ 100` operations just to get it to work.
- For some elements you have inline `onClick` attributes, for others you are using `document.addEventListener`.  Why make them different?  Pick one (ideally the latter) and be consistent with it, otherwise you're likely to confuse yourself.

Comment: I'm confused on which sections you updated and the order. Could you combine it all into one code block so I can see exactly while lines you were referencing. Like for update total, are you saying i need to completely remove my `let orderTotal = item + tip`?

Comment: @makerbaker: The additional logic was added inside the `if (event.target.matches("input[type=button]"))` block.  That's the specific code you execute when you click on a "tip" button.  It's definitely *very important* that you understand what code gets executed when you click on what button/element.

Comment: I tried to add your code snippets from where I think it should go, but I didn't get it to change correctly. Could you maybe edit my codepen JS or link one so I can see how you structured it?

Comment: So I added the `orderTotal += parseInt(tip * 100); // because your other values are multiplied by 100 for some reason
document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(orderTotal / 100).toFixed(2)}` inside of the if event matches button code, but the problem now is if I keep clicking the tips, the order total will continue going up to infinity and I only want the tip to be added once and change the total if I choose a different price tip

Comment: regarding the * 100 is because the API i am connecting with uses 1000 value to represent $10.00, so I don't know any other way to convert the values without having to add the  / 100

Comment: @makerbaker: For the increasing tip calculation, I've updated the code in the answer to account for that.  Now it's no longer updating the `orderTotal` value when selecting a tip, it's just adding the two together for the resulting display.  The `tip` and `orderTotal` values remain separate.  Overall though this code could definitely use some refactoring to clean it up and make the logic less confusing.

Comment: how would I make the orderTotal update after selecting a tip? because if I click a checkbox, then select a tip, then select another checkbox the orderTotal doesn't update unless I choose another tip again

Comment: @makerbaker: I recommend refactoring the code and separating concerns. (1) Create global variables for the order price, tip, total, and any other "page state" you want to track. (2) Create a function which updates the UI with the current values. (3) Create a function which re-calculates the values based on arguments to the function. (4) Create functions which respond to element clicks and calls the functions to update and display values. (5) Use `addEventListener` to bind those click functions to the target elements.

Comment: @makerbaker: Basically, you'll find code much simpler to understand and maintain if you separate out the different elements of functionality.  The central data/models that you track are one piece, displaying that data is another piece, updating that data is another piece, and handling UI interactions is another piece.

Answer (score -1):

Please read more about **let**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let 
You are defining a scope variable inside the function and when you click on the button it doesn't work because there isn't any event to call the function.
After that, you can define an object outside the function that stores your data when you want to call the function in different ways.

```
let data = {
  items: 0,
  tip: 0
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");

buttons.forEach((b) => {
  b.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches("input[type=button]")) {
      data.tip = parseInt(event.target.value);
      document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip: $${data.tip}`;
      showPrice();
    }
  });
});

function updatePrice() {
  data.items = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach((checkBox) => {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      data.items += +checkBox.value;
      showPrice();
    }
  });
}
function showPrice() {
  //Calculating Totals

  let orderTotal = data.items + data.tip;

  document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(
    data.items / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;

  document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(
    orderTotal / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't update any of the values

Answer (score -1):

- HTML - Changed instead of input type button used radio button.
- Javascript - Used same method as checkbox for radio button logic.

```js
function updatePrice() {
  //Adding Food
  let items = 0;

  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach((checkBox) => {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      items += +checkBox.value;
      document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(
        checkBox.value / 100
        ).toFixed(2)}`;
      }
  });
  
  

  //Adding Tip
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]").forEach((radioBox) => {
    if (radioBox.checked) {
      items += +radioBox.value;
      // update tip
      document.querySelector('#tip').innerHTML = `Tip: $${(
    radioBox.value / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`
    }
  });



  //Calculating Totals

  let orderTotal = items;

  

  document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(
    orderTotal / 100
  ).toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
    <h2>Order Details</h2>
        <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="1000" onChange="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item1">12 piece wings $10</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="700" onChange="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item2">6 piece wings $7</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="300" onChange="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item3">Large fries $3</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="payment">
    <h2>Payment Summary</h2>
    <p id="price">Food Total: $0.00</p>
    <p id="fee">Delivery Fee $0.00</p>
    <p id="tip">Tip: $0.00</p>
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="300" onChange="updatePrice()"> 3
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="500" onChange="updatePrice()"> 5
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="1000" onChange="updatePrice()"> 10
    <p id="total">Your order total is: $0.00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't update the tip value and I need to use buttons not radio

Comment: tip is updating now